# Comparing two Excel worksheet and display new data in a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I looked for the answer of my problem in all topics discussed on this platform such as Compare two Sheet and find differences, Macro to compare two worksheets & highlights differences and so on ... but I did not found what I was looking for.

My question is ; is there a possibility to compare two excel worksheets with a different layout as below? I'm willing to compare an historical worksheets versus a new worksheets and display in a third worksheet what was on the new worksheet that does not exist in the historical e.g :

[image]

I hope you will understand my question and be able to help me on this topic. I already have a code which compare two worksheet and show the difference but it's not enough for my problem.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareIt()
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Var As Variant
    Dim v()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim str As String

    ar = Sheet1.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        ReDim v(1 To UBound(ar, 2))
        For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
            For n = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                str = str & Chr(2) & ar(i, n)
                v(n) = ar(i, n)
            Next
            .Item(str) = v: str = ""
        Next
        ar = Sheet2.Cells(10, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(, UBound(v)).Value
        For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
            For n = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                str = str & Chr(2) & ar(i, n)
                v(n) = ar(i, n)
            Next
            If .exists(str) Then
                .Item(str) = Empty
            Else
                .Item(str) = v
            End If
            str = ""
        Next
        For Each arr In .keys
            If IsEmpty(.Item(arr)) Then .Remove arr
        Next
        Var = .items: j = .Count
    End With
    With Sheet3.Range("a1").Resize(, UBound(ar, 2))
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Value = ar
        If j > 0 Then
            .Offset(1).Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Var))
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dense, but I can't understand how you're getting your new sheet from your historical data and new data - also, a tip: When using example names, it's easier to use words that *aren't* so similar in appearance, like Tom, Mike and Harry, instead of Blabla, Blabli, Bloblo, etc...

Comment: Hi Dwirony,  I'm willing to get the new sheet based on what do not exist on the historical sheet.